# How to create Promise using other Promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am using `child-process-promise` [module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/child-process-promise). So I have something like this:

```
var promise = require('child-process-promise').spawn;

promise('some_command_producing_output')
    .then(function (result) {
        ...
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        ...
    });
```

What I want is to add some processing after command produced output in `stdout`. So finally I want to create a function to use like this:

```
RunCommandAndProcess('some_command_producing_output')
    .then(function (result) {
        ...
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        ...
    });
```

The function should use promise from `child-process-promise`, wait until successful result produced and return promise for processing data.

Comment: So, `function RunCommandAndProcess(x) { return spawn(x) }`? There's noting magic about promises, they're just values that you can pass around and return from your helper function.

Comment: The processing function, which I need to perform after spawning should be done asynchronously, using promise.

Comment: So insert `.then(process)`?

Comment: assuming `process` is returning promise, but I would like to combine them into single promise.

Comment: Yes, `process` can return a promise. [`then` works just like that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22562045/1048572).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really just

```
var spawn = require('child-process-promise').spawn;
function RunCommandAndProcess(cmd) {
    return spawn(cmd).then(function process(result) {
        … // do processing
        return …;
    });
}
```

Comment: So in processing routine I have to create and return another promise, in order to make `RunCommandAndProcess` thenable, right? I would like to have `RunCommandAndProcess.then(...)`.

Comment: You can return or throw anything. The `then()` call always returns a promise that resolves with whatever result your callback has.